# How to Create a GUI Process in hidden mode?

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to create a process (Internet Explorer "iexplore.exe" to be precise) in hidden mode, with no success.

I have tried with the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL WINAPI GetIePath(LPTSTR Buffer, DWORD Length)
{
    HKEY hKey;

    if(::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\App Paths\\IEXPLORE.EXE"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return FALSE;

    if(::RegQueryValueEx(hKey, NULL, 0, NULL, (LPBYTE)Buffer, &Length) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        ::RegCloseKey(hKey);
        return FALSE;
    }

    ::RegCloseKey(hKey);
    return TRUE;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //::ShellExecute(NULL, /*_T("open")*/ NULL, _T("iexplore.exe"), _T("https://www.google.com"), NULL, SW_FORCEMINIMIZE);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFO SI = { 0 };
    SI.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    SI.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    SI.wShowWindow = SW_FORCEMINIMIZE;

    TCHAR lpsziepath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };

    if (!GetIePath(lpsziepath, MAX_PATH - 1))
        return 1;

    if(!::CreateProcess(lpsziepath, _T("iexplore.exe https://www.google.com") /*::GetCommandLine()*/, NULL, NULL, FALSE, /*CREATE_SUSPENDED*/ 0, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI))
        return 1;

    //::ResumeThread(PI.hThread);

    //if ((hwnd = ::FindWindow(_T("IEFrame"), _T("https://www.google.com/ - Internet Explorer") /*NULL*/)) == NULL)
    //  return 1;

    //::ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);

    return 0;
}
```

**SW_HIDE** flag has never worked for me whereas **SW_FORCEMINIMIZE** works but it is not stable (does not guarantee to always force it in the hidden state, it sometimes crates the process in a normal state "shown").

is there a better way of doing this ?

Thank you for your understanding.

**EDIT:**
I have found that only the first process will be created hidden with my code, If I try to create other instances using the launcher exe (the code exe) all the IE instances will then be created in normal mode (shown).

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: Probably the real solution involves not starting IE at all

Comment: Also note that the `wShowWindow` flag is *advisory* at best. The launched application is not *required* to honor it. Most apps will, but some don't.

Comment: A well-designed app *intentionally* ignores an SW_HIDE request.  Starting an app and giving the user no option to stop it other than by using Task Manager is a problem.  It is a malware vector on any program that does something internetty.  Google doesn't like bots either, it does know how to stop them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to start IE in the current desktop, you can try an alternative approach. `Start IE in a hidden/virtual desktop`

Look into [CreateDesktopA/W](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682124(v=vs.85).aspx) and after creating it you can use [SetThreadDesktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686250(v=vs.85).aspx)`1` in order to set all further calls to this desktop.

From this point you can call `CreateProcessA/W` to create an IE window on that desktop, and do whatever you wish with it. Then you can call `SetThreadDesktop` again to set the process execution back to the original user desktop.

To get the original desktop you can use [GetThreadDesktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683232(v=vs.85).aspx) with [GetCurrentThreadId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183(v=vs.85).aspx) before you move the current thread context to the new desktop. Then restore it with `SetThreadDesktop` after you're done with it.

**CODE**

```
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE CurrBase, HINSTANCE PrevBase, LPSTR SomeArgs, INT ShowStatus) {
    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFOW SI = { 0 };
    SI.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);
    SI.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    SI.wShowWindow = SW_FORCEMINIMIZE;

    WCHAR lpsziepath[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };

    if (!GetIePath(lpsziepath, MAX_PATH - 1))
        return 1;
    lpsziepath[lstrlenW(lpsziepath)/* (* sizeof(WCHAR)) */] = UNICODE_NULL;

    // create the hidden desktop
    HDESK hiddenDesktop = CreateDesktopA("MyHiddenIEDesktop", NULL, NULL, 0, GENERIC_ALL, NULL);
    if (hiddenDesktop) {
        // get the thread for the current desktop
        HDESK currDesktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId()); 
        // move to the hidden desktop
        if (SetThreadDesktop(hiddenDesktop)) { 
            // Before calling CreateProcessW you need to tell it which desktop to open the process in
            SI.lpDesktop = TEXT("MyHiddenIEDesktop"); 
            // here processes will with `SI` structure will be created in a hidden "window" / environment
            CreateProcessW(lpsziepath, TEXT("iexplore.exe https://www.google.com"), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI);
            // Wait until CreateProcessW finishes execution, and then move on afterwards
            WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, INFINITE);
            // move back to the original desktop after CreateProcessW is called
            SetThreadDesktop(currDesktop);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**NOTE**

I just wrote this code from the top of my head (as I am away from my desktop right now), but according to how it looks to me, it will work for you! If anything, just play around with it.

Comment: Your code works except for 2 problems:  1) I have to wait a little bit after **::CreateProcess** with **::Sleep(3000);** or I will get an exception error.  2) a new instance process of **ctfmon.exe** will be created in the new desktop.

Comment: 1) Sleep(3000) shouldnt be needed, maybe even smaller like Sleep(100 or 200) the IE window needs to register itself in the hidden window before you switch to the new context. You can use `WaitForSingleObject` instead so it will wait an appropriate amount of time (shortest as possible) before IE registers its window classes and initialize on the hidden desktop.

2) ctfmon.exe is created when a new hidden desktop is registered. This happens in any given scenario. You need a rootkit to hide it.

3) I have updated my answer, you can accept it by giving me the "Checkmark" on the question.

Comment: **WaitForSingleObject** returns only when the process has finished execution, not when it registers its window.

Comment: I think it should be **WaitForInputIdle** instead.

Comment: @Tomay It doesn't matter because the `WaitFor` wrappers are just for semantics. Internally (at kernel level) they each call the same `KeWaitForMultipleObjects` call, it's all a matter of how the stack is prepared prior to that call. But at the end of the day, the result is the same (because when execution finishes, either all windows are registered, or an error occurred) - so it's better to use `WaitForSingleObject` as that way you can also get the exit code and handle it if necessary.